# RgoogleMap on Shiny /R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, rgooglemaps

I would like to change the map which I am using on the following app:

[image]

Right now I am working with worldHires, but I would like to use a nicer map (with all the respect), like google maps.

Trying to use RgoogleMaps, I copied the following example for Canada:

```
library(RgoogleMaps)

  lat=c(48,64) 
  lon=c(-140,-110) 
  center=c(mean(lat), mean(lon))
  zoom=5
  terrmap=GetMap(
  center=center,
  zoom=zoom,
  maptype="terrain",
  destfile = "terrain.png")
```

However, I got just a link:

```
 [1] "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?
 center=56,-125&zoom=5&size=640x640&maptype=terrain&format=png32&sensor=true"
```

Do you know how can I put it directly on my app?

Answer (score 0):

Your code loads an image from Google Maps and stores it in `terrain.png` in your working directory. The return value is the URL of the image, as it should be.

You can display the map using:

```
tmp <- PlotOnStaticMap(terrmap, lat = NA, lon = NA,
                      col=c( 'red','blue','green'), add=FALSE)
```

See the documentation for [`PlotOnStatisMap(...)`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RgoogleMaps/docs/PlotOnStaticMap) for more details.

Comment: I was already trying that, but it seams to get really slow... and at the end it doesn't open...
Btw: what's the "col=c( 'red','blue','green'), add=FALSE"

Comment: It works for me in RStudio. Since you did not post your Shiny code, I can't comment on that. I used `col=` because sometimes the maps render in B/W if you don't do that, but in this case you don't need it. And the rendering is really slow - takes about 0.5s on my system.